# How is the createImageBitmap options object used?

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap

I am currently trying to test out Mozilla's [documentation of createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapFactories/createImageBitmap), while passing options to the function.

My JS code is as follows:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
image = new Image();

image.onload = function() {
      Promise.all([
        createImageBitmap(this, {resizeWidth: 200, resizeHeight: 200}),
      ]).then(function(sprites) {
        ctx.drawImage(sprites[0], 0, 0);
      });
    }

image.src = 'logo.png';
```

When I run it, I get the following error from Chromium (version 51):

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createImageBitmap' on 'Window': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

If I do not pass an object into `createImageBitmap()`, the image is rendered onto my `<canvas>` element without a problem. However, I need to be able to resize it through JS. Since this is a brand new standard, I can't find anywhere that actually explains how to pass the optional "options" object into `createImageBitmap()`.
Any help is greatly appreciated- thanks very much in advance.

Comment: According to the mdn page you linked, options parameter is only supported since v52 in chrome.

Comment: Oh my GOOODDDD. I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much for pointing that out, I was so frustrated. Been testing it out on an updated version, and some options work- but it seems that the resizeWidth and resizeHeight parameters do not work. I have a feeling that this is because it takes "long integers" and I'm not passing the right param in. Any ideas?

Comment: It's the first time I play with it, but on my chrome canary (v54) it does work in a strange way : only upscaling does work correctly, downscaling will actually crop the image, but well, it can be done with `drawImage` parameters anyway.

Comment: That's a shame. My assumption is that Chrome does not yet support any of the parameters except flipY. I'll see if I can note that on Mozilla's doc. Also, I completely forgot that drawImage can take custom sizes, thanks again

Comment: Once again, from my tests, upscaling did work correctly.

Comment: Right. I'd meant the current public release of Chrome, v52

Comment: Resizing still doesn't appear to work in Chrome 61 :-(